# Creating global definition script?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script for a main script to reference as a set of commonly used terms. For example, we currently have in one of our main automation scripts

```
LAT = ['Lat', 'lat', 'LAT', 'Latitude', 'latitude', 'LATITUDE',     'SITE_EST_LATITUDE']
```

which is then referenced later as

```
for n in LAT:
with open(report_list) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if field == n:
                lat = field
```

My company handles telecommunications and reports are regularly pulled from multiple sources which all use different terminology for referencing latitude/longitude. Ideally what we'd like to do is have our script reference another script which would contain all of these definitions (examples include latitude, longitude, state names, city names, etc...). So there is a lot of information -- thus making it a bit easier to just have a script reference the library of terms as opposed to typing them out in every new script we create.

Bottom line, I'm not super advanced with Python so I'm not sure how to create a new script that houses these terms (preferably in a CSV) and can be used as a reference in other scripts.

Comment: Focus on converting the csv to a table, then use table/field/cursor objects to do your mapping and your lookup. For field in arcpy.ListFields(Table): If field.name in LAT: DO

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, there are many ways to implement such a library, making this opinion-based, plus library design is broader than our usual "Focused question / Best answer" topics, and finally,  to avoid becoming a coding service, we ask that code questions contain code (yes, you have *some* code, but not the important parts). You might be better off researching how software engineers create Python libraries than asking here. Generic data access libraries are possible, but often consume years of effort.

Comment: There appears to be no GIS component to this pure Python question which I think would be better researched at [so].